# Jquery image slider Image comes down and fades out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a image slider in Jquery, as I move my image clicking the forward or backward button the image which has to change comes down and then fades out. Its like a small fluctuation. Why is this happening ? 
JSfiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/76xjmfjo/2/

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="back" src="http://placehold.it/50x20/000000"></img>

    <div class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/940x350">
        </div>

        <div class="slide ">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/940x350">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/940x350">
        </div>

    </div>
    <img class="forward" src="http://placehold.it/50x20/000000"></img>
</div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container{
    width: 980px;
    margin:  0 auto;
}

.slide-container{
    position: relative;
    margin : 0 auto;
    width: 958px;
    height: 368px;

}
.slide{
    width: 940px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 5px solid black ;
    z-index: 1;
}

.active{
    position: relative;
}

.back,.forward{
    top: 150px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 10000;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.forward{
    left: 950px;
}
```

---

**jQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var speed = 500;

  //showing the first image (adding class active)
  $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
  $('.slide').hide();
  $('.active').show();

  //assigning events for the forward and backward buttons
  $('.forward').on('click', function () {
    nextSlide();
  });
  $('.back').on('click', function () {
    prevSlide();
  });

  //next Slide function
  function nextSlide() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
    if ($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
      $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
      $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
    } 
    else {
      $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
    }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
    $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
  }

  //Previous slide function
  function prevSlide() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
    if ($('.oldActive').is(':first-child')) {
      $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
      $('.slide').last().addClass('active');
    } 
    else {
      $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
    }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.slide').fadeOut(500);
    $('.active').fadeIn(500);
  }

});
```

Comment: You can prevent the image from appearing down by adding `overflow: hidden;` to `.slide-container`

Comment: @Ahmed I added that the problem is solved but the problem is when I click the back button the image goes off  for a micro second and comes back.

Comment: Because of position relative of .active image. In one moment -  image have absolute and relative position in the same time (.slide is relative, if i remember well)... If you set position to absolute, 'jump' disappears: https://jsfiddle.net/76xjmfjo/3/

Comment: @nevermind `.slide` is absolute and `.slider-container` is relative. Your method when I add `absolute` to .active image disappears. Please specify where I should add what. If you see when I click the front button the animation is smooth but when I click back button this happens.

Comment: .active{
 position: absolute;
} too, as i can see no need for relative positioning?

Comment: @nevermind If you see when I click the front button the animation is smooth but when I click back button this happens. When `slide-container` is _relative_  `.slide` is _absolute_ and `.active` is _absolute_ it disappears when clicked.

Comment: No, it is not smooth even when you click next button. Both button works the same (tested your original fiddle now)... fadein/out changes display to none or block, and if element is relatively positioned - jump exists... P.S. it happens on third click -> when you go forward....

Comment: @nevermind yes it does then what is the solution, if I add `.active` to _absolute_ the image disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fadeIn $('.active') on complete function of $('.slide');

```
$('.slide').fadeOut(speed, function(){
    $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
});
```